# Indexed view forcing non-optimal column type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are trying to speed up some of our stored procs by reducing implicit conversions.  One of the issues we are trying to figure out is how to fix several indexed views similar to this:

`Time.UserID is INT`
`Time.TimeUnit is DECIMAL(9,2)`
`Time.BillingRate is MONEY`

```
Select 
    UserID, 
    SUM(TimeUnit) as Hours, 
    SUM(TimeUnit*BillingRate) as BillableDollars
FROM 
    Time
GROUP BY 
    UserID
```

gives us a view with the columns:

```
UserID(int, null)  
Hours(decimal(38,2), null)  
BillableDollars(decimal(38,6), null)
```

We would prefer to have `Hours(decimal(9,2),null)` and `BillableDollars(money,null)`.

`CAST(SUM(TimeUnit*BillingRate) AS MONEY) as BillableDollars`

Returned:

> Cannot create the clustered index 'ix_indexName' on
>   view 'x.dbo.vw_viewName' because the
>   select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate
>   function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of
>   aggregate function or grouping column from select list.

And we were worried about the efficiency of `SUM(CAST(TimeUnit*BillingRate AS MONEY)) as BillableDollars`

What would be the best way to preserve these column types or is there a 'best practice'?

Comment: Did you TRY the performance of `SUM(CAST)`? Did you also compare `MONEY` to a more practical data type (such as `DECIMAL(9,2)`) IMHO?

Answer (score 2):

I might try adding a derived (actualized) "BillableDollars" column to the Time table with the conversion applied:

```
CONVERT(MONEY,(TimeUnit*BillingRate))
```

I've used money but, of course, the conversion could be to whatever data type most effectively meets your needs.

I believe this will allow you to have the indexed view while summing on the calculated billable dollars.

I expect that the reason you're getting a larger precision in the view datatype than the one in the table data type is that the sum of a bunch of numbers with a precision of 9 is adding up to a number that needs a precision greater than 9.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your indexed view in second "casting" view like this

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT  CAST(UserID AS INT)              AS UserID
        , CAST(TimeUnit AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TimeUnit
        , CAST(BillingRate AS MONEY)     AS BillingRate
FROM    MyViewIndexed WITH (NOEXPAND)
```

As a bonus you can include `NOEXPAND` hint so the underlying indexed view is actually utilized by query optimizer on less "advanced" editions of MSSQL.